# Double For Loops in an API query

Tags: python

I want the script to run through the stocks in the stock list and each time it queries the API for it to use a new key from key_list.

For example

- stock_ticker_1 and api_key_1
- stock_ticker_2 and api_key_2
- stock_ticker_3 and api_key_3

This is how the lists look.
I also added a list that has stock and key together. On the off chance that is the correct way to set this up?

The keys below work to test this example, so feel free to use them as well. I guess the best way to test is to write something random in the other keys and see if an error will appear.

```
##### STOCK WATCH LIST  #####
stock_list = [
    'TSLA', 
    'BA', 
    'MSFT', 

]

##### API KEY LIST #####
key_list = [ 
    'FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M', 
    '8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0', 
    'H2553YZZNPBUB7NC', 
]

##### MULTI-DIMENSIONAL LIST STOCK + KEY #####
big_stock_list = [
['TSLA','FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M'],
['BA','8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0'],
['MSFT','H2553YZZNPBUB7NC'],
]
```

I am completely lost with how to initiate a new key for each stock. Each attempt seems to just use one key to run the API access for every stock.

```
  # Created a new file with all the keys in it
  # Tried to randomply pick a key, hopeing each new stock would be a random key
lines = open('keys').read().splitlines()
keys=random.choice(lines)

  #Tried to create the for loop inside the for loop with the hope it would go down the list 
 for item in stock_list:
    stock_ticker=item

    for item in key_list:
        keys = item
        
    # also tried
    for item in key_list:
        keys = random.choice(item)
        
  # in the actual API query I added the random key line
    base_url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'
    params = {'function': 'OVERVIEW',
            'symbol': stock_ticker,
            'apikey': keys = random.choice(item)}
```

This is currently how I have the code set up

```python
import pandas as pd
import time
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime as dt
import requests
import os
import json
from tabulate import tabulate



##### STOCK WATCH LIST  #####
stock_list = [
    'TSLA', 
    'BA', 
    'MSFT', 

]

key_list = [ 
    'FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M', 
    '8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0', 
    'H2553YZZNPBUB7NC', 
]

##### MULTI DIMENSIONAL LIST #####
big_stock_list = [
['TSLA','FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M'],
['BA','8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0'],
['MSFT','H2553YZZNPBUB7NC'],
]


##### ANALYZE STOCKS INSIDE STOCK LIST #####
for item in stock_list:
    stock_ticker=item

    for item in key_list:
        keys = random.choice(item)

    # STEPS THAT ARE HAPPENING
        # 1. Grabs stock_ticker from Stock List
        # 2. Grabs key for that specific stock_sticker
        # 3. Uses API Key to open each library with that stock_ticker 
        # 4. Creates data points usings formulas 
        # 5. Outputs the desired metrics 

    ###### ACCESS TO EACH ALPHA VANTAGE LIBRARY ######
    base_url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'
    params = {'function': 'OVERVIEW',
            'symbol': stock_ticker,
            'apikey': keys}                     
    response_data_overview = requests.get(base_url, params=params)

    ###### DATA POINTS FORUMLAS ######
    data_overview_MarketCapitalization = response_data_overview.json()['MarketCapitalization']

    ###### ANALYSIS OUTPUT ######
    print("The Market Cap for {} is = {}".format(stock_ticker,data_overview_MarketCapitalization))
```

Just to clarify one more time. This code works as is, and it cycles through each stock_ticker in stock_list to output the market cap. But the problem is that it uses one key to run the API access for all the stocks in the list, instead of using a unique key for each stock.

Any help or insight on where I am tripping up with this is much appreciated :) I tried to look up nested loops but I can't wrap my head around the documentation.

I am very new to python and coding, so apologies for the novice question if this is something straight forward. Trying to do 100 days of daily coding and see what happens haha, currently on day 34 >.<

---

Update - Dictionary List Attempt

I set up the dictionary as instructed and the code works but it still doesn't cycle through the keys.

I added some fake keys to the dictionary

```
stock_dict = {
'TSLA':'FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M',
'BA':'ddddddddddddd8HCU3JWL953555WE0VR0',
'MSFT':'ddddddddddH2553YZ5ZNPB5555UB7NC'
}
```

The printed out results are the picture below. Somehow it used the fake keys?

[image]

Comment: `for item in stock_list: for item in key_list:` don't do this use different name in inner loop

Comment: Use the `stock_list` item index as the `key_list` index. Since Python lists work with out of bound indices it should work fine.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Stock queries and APIs are nothing to do with your problem. Create some code which all it does is print the combinations you want. Also, look at [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Thanks for the link to documentation. That one is really helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a
[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

It'd look kind of like you set up `big_stock_list`:

```
stock_dict = {
    'TSLA': 'FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M',
    ...
}
```

Then you access the dictionary's keys and values to get the stock ticker and key:

```
for ticker, key in stock_dict.items():
    ...
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to add my code to save my life in this comment box. But I did set up the dictionary as you suggested. When I changed the API key for BA and MSFT to be gibberish, and the code still worked. It showed the result of all 3 stocks. Which means that it only used the API key from the first stock TSLA

Comment: Yea so this way seems to solve issue with rotating the keys. The issue I guess I am having is with the API. I put in blank words and it still ran the code and outputted the reuslts. It's like if alpha vantage stored my ip address so it doesn't matter about key anymore? I guess I need to figure out how to rotate ip addresses

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I have it figured out, but I'll summarize the problem:

> You have a list of N pairs, each pair consisting of a ticker and an api key. You want to iterate through all tickers, and use that tickers corresponding api key to do some operation

If that's true, in your current implementaion, your usage of random choice seems peculiar:

```
##### ANALYZE STOCKS INSIDE STOCK LIST #####
for item in stock_list:
    stock_ticker=item

    for item in key_list:
        keys = random.choice(item)
```

to me this seems like it's going in the direction of:

> "Use a random API key" not "Use the corresponding API key".

If I were in your shoes, I would be doing something more along the lines of this:

```
big_stock_list = [
['TSLA','FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M'],
['BA','8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0'],
['MSFT','H2553YZZNPBUB7NC'],
]

for pair in big_stock_list:
    current_ticker = pair[0]
    current_key = pair[1]

    print('_______________________________')
    print('Current Ticker: {}'.format(current_ticker))
    print('Current Key: {}'.format(current_key))

    print('Doing something with that ticker and key...')
```

this iterates through all the `pair`s in `big_stock_list`, and extracts the ticker and key from the current `pair`. this code snippet results in this output:

```
_______________________________
Current Ticker: TSLA
Current Key: FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M
Doing something with that ticker and key...
_______________________________
Current Ticker: BA
Current Key: 8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0
Doing something with that ticker and key...
_______________________________
Current Ticker: MSFT
Current Key: H2553YZZNPBUB7NC
Doing something with that ticker and key...
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

as you can see, I'm going through each pair, grabbing the ticker and api key, and printing them out. Naturally, you can replace 'printing them out' with using them in your `response_data_overview = requests.get(base_url, params=params)` function

---

Also, P.S. as a previous answer suggested, using dictionaries is probably more "pythonic" than a list of lists. Changing my original implementation to use dictionaries looks like this:

```
big_stock_list = {
'TSLA':'FH6OZB7R2I4IBX4M',
'BA':'8HCU3JWL93WE0VR0',
'MSFT':'H2553YZZNPBUB7NC',
}

for current_ticker, current_key in big_stock_list.items():

    print('_______________________________')
    print('Current Ticker: {}'.format(current_ticker))
    print('Current Key: {}'.format(current_key))

    print('Doing something with that ticker and key...')
```

it results in the same output

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went through your steps and I found the issue. I did random keys part as any attempt to have the keys be unique haha. But the issue seems to be with the api itself. My ip address is saved it seems with some key for alpha vantage. So regardless of what API key I put in or even random gibberish for key, it still connects using an old key. I don't really understand how that works, but I'll try messing with how to rotate ips :)